# Recording an saving sounds to file with ActionScript 3. NOT from the microphone

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, export, wav

I am trying to create a Flash application(more like a game) where a user can add sounds to a timeline and then play the resulting "song". That is not really hard to do, and the resulting track can be saved and played within my app, but the problem is that I would like to export the created track as a .wav(or .mp3). I know that recording from a microphone with MicRecorder is possible and then the record can be exported with WaveEncoder, but I didn't find a way to create a custom sound stream from multiple sounds and than export it. Is this possible?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not get the question. But if its what i think it is, you have to create your own meta data.
Exemple; have a bank of sound effects (drums, guitars etc...) and have a time in which it should be played. Wrap a class around the as3 Sound class, add a time member. So when the user places a files on Sound effect on the track you can write the time at which its played and then play it accordingly. Might not be the best way to do it but it would work. About Saving it as a mp3 files theirs theirs surely an mp3 encoder class somewhere. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes you got it right and that was also the solution I thought about, but my problem was not how to play the resulting track, but how to export it as a wav or mp3.